# Serialize generic dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, generics

I want to serialize an object. But I want that the object has to be a dictionary (of tkey and tvalue any type).

My code so far:

```
public static byte[] Serialize<T>(this T source)
{
    try
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();

            binaryFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, source);

            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return default(byte[]);
    }
}
```

Now I want that "source" can only be a Dictionary like Dictionary<int, string>, Dictionary<foo, int>, ...

Comment: Only one object is generally required for serialization and how we know all in c# is object so ... . Problems can arise later with the deserialization

Comment: And what help do you need?

Comment: And `catch(Exception e) { return default(byte[]); }` is horrible.

Comment: ***DON'T USE** BinaryFormatter*!!!!!! The class is unsafe, generates deprecation warnings and is actively being removed from the .NET BCL which means methods that depend on it will break sooner or later.

Comment: What kind of serialization do you want to begin with? JSON serialization already works. If you want binary serialization, you first need to decide what format to use. You could use protobuf, used by gRPC, which is standardized, cross-platform and easy to use.

Comment: Check [Protobuf In C# .NET](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2022/01/13/protobuf-in-c-net-part-2-serializing-deserializing/). protobuf supports dictionaries as `map` elements. These [unit tests of the protobuf-net library](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/blob/main/src/Examples/DictionaryTests.cs) use dictionaries

Comment: @Enigmativity so what do you suggest instead my try-catch-block

Comment: @bergungsdackel - Write code that doesn't throw. You should only ever catch specific exceptions that you can meaningfully handle. Have a read of this: https://ericlippert.com/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static byte[] Serialize<T,V>(this Dictionary<T,V> source) 
{
    try
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();

            binaryFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, source);

            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return default(byte[]);
    }
}
```

with this definition only Dictionary<Key,Value> can be passed to the method.

In example https://dotnetfiddle.net/SQY6zs you can see that `Serialize()` can be applied to `Dictionary<int,bool>` but not to `int`